# How do I store a 800 row, 25 column file in an N-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, vector, rust

I am looking for a way to store a 800 row, 25 column file in an array. I have figured out how to store the data from a CSV in 25 different vectors, but the code looks really messy because I have to declare all the different vectors.

I am very used to the `array` function in Python and I was wondering if there was a way to do this in Rust. I found the [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/) external crate, but I can't figure out how to use it for 6+ dimensional arrays. This is what my code looks like for a 2-dimensional array, you can imagine how messy it would look with 25 different vectors, `f` declarations and `vector.push()` functions.

```
extern crate rand;
extern crate csv;

fn print(v: Vec<f64>) {
    println!("New vector");
    for x in &v {
        println!("{}  ", x);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_file("./data.csv").unwrap();
    let mut v1 = Vec::new();
    let mut v2 = Vec::new();
    for record in rdr.decode() {
        let (f1, f2): (f64, f64) = record.unwrap();
        println!("({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {})", f1, f2);
        v1.push(f1);
        v2.push(f2);

    }
    print(v1);
    print(v2);
}
```

Comment: Quick note: you do not need to rush to accept an answer. Once an answer is accepted other people are less likely to come and try to answer, so sometimes waiting a bit to accept (say, a day or so, because timezones) will lead to you getting better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what N-Dimensional means.

An array with rows and columns only has **2** dimensions, and therefore can be represented easily as `Vec<Vec<f64>>`.

I would therefore expect code like:

```
fn main() {
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_file("./data.csv").unwrap();

    let result = Vec::new();

    for record in rdr.decode() {
        let row: Vec<f64> = record.unwrap();
        println!("{:?}", row);
        result.push(row);
    }
}
```

Taking advantage of the fact that [`Decodable`](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/rustc_serialize/trait.Decodable.html) is implemented for `Vec<T>`.